# ob_post.post AJAX IE issue

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, obout

I have a javascript that runs an obout javascript that looks like this

```
ob_post.post(null, "functionNameHere", function () { });
```

This function works great on all browsers except for IE, I am not certain about all IE version but 11 does not work atleast.

The function is being run on an on blur event but I've played around with alerts here and there and everything works great except for this part. Where it does the AJAX.

I am not really experienced with obout and I haven't really made this website either, just updating it a bit here and there.

Does the obout just not support IE/IE11 that much?

Comment: Did you try using fiddler? Does the request even leave the browser? Try debugging with developer tools and check if there are any errors that show up in the Scripts window.

Comment: @Nilesh No it never leaves the browser, or it does not atleast never reach the .NET server(debugging never starts) while on all other browsers it works plus debugging starts. The javascript on blur event ALWAYS works and always works up to the obout JS function, then it suddenly dies.

Comment: I dont have IE11 on my laptop, but with a quick google search I found this **[link](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14475)**. Check if that gives you some insight. Try installing IE 10 and try the post request again.

Comment: @Nilesh I'm running Visual Studio to create a localhost though not just opening a HTML file, plus the issue exists on an live-server too. But I will try some older IE versions

Comment: @Nilesh I just tried the compability mode in IE11 and all available modes there (5,7,8,9 and 10) works except for Edge(11) So 11 is the issue here. I guess obouts JS function doesn't support it.

Comment: Its not that obouts does not support IE11, I belive obouts is using jquery under the hood and IE11 handles the XMLhttprequest differently and thats the reason jquery fails to create a xmlhhtprequest object. Are you referencing a JQUERY js file? What is the version of JQuery that you use?